# elasticsearch - search with regex involving space

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I want to perform searching using regular expression involving whitespace in elasticsearch.
I have already set my field to not_analyzed. And it's mapping is just like

```
"type1": {
   "properties": {
      "field1": {
         "type": "string",
         "index": "not_analyzed",
         "store": true
      }
   }
}
```

And I input two value for test,

```
"field1":"XXX YYY ZZZ"
"field1":"XXX ZZZ YYY"
```

And i do some case using regex query /XXX YYY/ 
(I want to use this query to find record1 but not record2)

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "/XXX YYY/"
        }
    }
}
```

But it return 0 results.

However if I search without using regex (without the forward slash '/'), both record1 and record2 are returned.

Is that in elasticsearch, i cannot search using regex query involving space?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25316837/3087680

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a ''term'' query that doesn't [tokenise](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) the search query by breaking it down into smaller parts. More about the term query here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-term-query.html

There's a special breed of term queries that allows you to use regexes called regexp queries. That should match any whitespaces as well: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using your `query string`, but your regexp is just missing a tiny part, i.e. the `.*` at the end. If you run that you'll get the single result you expect.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "/XXX YYY.*/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for my use-case. `"/XXX YYY.*/"` *will* match a string like `XXX YYY blah blah blah`. However, `"/XXX YYY .* something else/"` will *not* match `XXX YYY blah blah something else`... No clue yet as to why...

Comment: @Tabbernaut feel free to create a new question for your specific issue

Comment: Figured out a way: `"/XXX YYY.*/" AND "/.*something else/"` works. It just can't be done in a single clause, I guess.

Comment: @Tabbernaut not sure about your use case, feel free to create a new question

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`regexp`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) queries to achieve this. Mind you, the query performance may be slow. The below query will search for all documents in which the value of `field1` contains "XXX YYY".

```
POST <index_name>/type1/_search
{
   "query": {
      "regexp": {
         "field1": ".*XXX YYY.*"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i dont think that recognizes the space character. i also tried \s but that did not work

Comment: @AbtPst Why do you say that? Note that the field "field1" is marked as "not_analyzed". That will result in Elasticsearch not tokenizing around whitespaces. So my query will work.