# elasticsearch span_near query false hits

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a text field which contains an xml-document where I try to find this kind of match:

`<Payer> [...] bic=\"123456789\" [...] </Payer>`

with the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
            { "span_term" : { "field" : "payer" }},
            { "span_term" : { "field" : "bic" }},
            { "span_term" : { "field" : "123456789" }},
            { "span_term" : { "field" : "payer"}}
            ],
            "slop" : 500,
            "in_order" : true
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I get wrong matches if xml-document contains something like:

```
<Payer>bic=\"111111111\"</Payer><Payee>bic=\"123456789\"</Payee><Payer>bic=\"222222222\"</Payer>
```

Query finds `PayeE` instead of `PayeR`. From `elastic` point of view it is still valid.

Any ideas I can prevent this "greedy" search?

As far as I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313051/elasticsearch-and-regex-queries) topic regexp is not an option because "*Elasticsearch (and lucene) don't support full Perl-compatible regex syntax"*. It means `regexp-query` matches tokens, not the whole string.

I also tried to make last `span_term` like `/payer` or `\\/payer` or `</payer` but it finds nothing at all.

Comment: Maybe [`span_not`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-not-query.html) can help here. BTW, there are things Lucene regexp can do in a better way than PCRE one. E.g. you may use `<Payer>~(<Payee>)bic=\"123456789\"~(<Payee>)</Payer>` to match a whole string that will not match the unwanted string you provided.

Comment: what's the problem here? you want only to find exactly substring with payer?

Comment: Mysterion, yess

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, yes it doesn't match the unwanted string, but it doesn't match wanted either :( if I use opposite regexp `<payee>~(<payer>)bic=\"123456789\"~(<payer>)</payer>`

Comment: Because it requires a full string match.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, `span_not` solved the problem. Post an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a [`span_not`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-not-query.html#query-dsl-span-not-query) query:

> Removes matches which overlap with another span query. The span not query maps to Lucene `SpanNotQuery`.